# Nuxtjs - 3rd Party Script causes "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document')" loop in console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a 3rd party ad script that I inject into my nuxt component using postscribe. The website works fine. However if I try to navigate away from the page without letting the script to finish loading. I get hit with the error loop below (in the browser console). The error show every millisecond and it doesn't go away unless I refresh the page.

`invoke.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document')`

This is the code that I inject using postscribe

```
this.$postscribe('#myDivId', `
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            atOptions = {
                                'key' : 'fiajiewfoj3jiosfo',
                                'format' : 'iframe',
                                'height' : 90,
                                'width' : 728,
                                'params' : {}
                                };
                                document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://script-src.com/12345767890/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
                            <\/script>`
                );
```

I did try injecting it using vanilla javascript but that did not work as well.

```
let a= document.getElementById("myDiv")
let basePath = document.createElement('script')
basePath.type = "text/javascript"
basePath.setAttribute('async', 'true');
basePath.innerHTML = `<script type="text/javascript">
                            atOptions = {
                                'key' : 'fiajiewfoj3jiosfo',
                                'format' : 'iframe',
                                'height' : 90,
                                'width' : 728,
                                'params' : {}
                                };
                                document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://script-src.com/12345767890/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
                            <\/script>`
a.appendChild(basePath)
```

It also isn't fixed, if I'm running it with if (process.client) i.e.
`if(process.client){this.$postscribe.......}`

I suspect it has something to do with document.write() but I have no experience with document.write() and its behaviour.

Note: I didn't put in into the head() because I want this to appear in a particular div / component.